# UITableView bottom rows arent visible

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a TableViewController that is just a UIViewController with a tableview in it

i add this table view controller to many screens as a child view controller

all works well, except for the fact that the last 2 rows of it, are sometimes not visible

they are there, and if half of it is visible, i'm able to see part of the data

this is my setup:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
_purchaseInvoiceListTable = (TableViewController *)[self.storyboard viewController:[TableViewController class]];
_purchaseDataSource = [[PurchaseInvoiceListDataSource alloc]init];
User *user = [self.userSettings getUserDetails];
[_purchaseDataSource setPurchaseSummaryInfo:[user purchases]];
[_purchaseDataSource setGroupDelegate:self];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable setDataSource:_purchaseDataSource];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable.view setFrame:_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer.bounds];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer addSubview:[_purchaseInvoiceListTable view]];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:_purchaseInvoiceListTable];
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable didMoveToParentViewController:self];
_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
[_purchaseInvoiceListTable.tableView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
```

Comment: Depending on the size/frame of your _purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer, the following "_purchaseInvoiceListTableContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;" might make the overflow not visible if the frame is too large. Obviously, if the frame/bounds goes outside of the screen it's not visible either but that is not obvious from your supplied code snippet. ;)

Comment: try by setting   [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 50, 0)];

Comment: @Shan put your answer i'll accept it, 50 was not enough, 200 did the trick. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case try by setting the `contentInset` property of UITableView

for example

```
 [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 0, 200, 0)];
```